# A problem in mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, celestial-mechanics

This is an apparently simple problem that I could not solve. The source is a colleague who interviewed for the European space agency.

You are standing in a field with a chronometer and a camera. Someone throws a ball (a point mass) in the air, with an unknown speed and velocity. You can take pictures with the camera and record the time between pictures with the chronometer, but you can’t directly measure the distance between you and the ball. How many pictures do you need to take to determine where the ball will hit the ground?

Assume that the earth is flat, that $g$ is known to arbitrary precision, that air has no effect and that the trajectory is generic. Assume moreover that the camera is at a known position and at a known height above the ground (may assume that the height is $0$ if useful for the solution).

**Attempts at solution**

The state of the ball is determined by six parameters, but we only want to know where the ball hits the ground, so we may need only five or less parameters.

The first picture gives two parameters and the second one three, so two pictures may be sufficient. My gut feeling is that they are not, but I wouldn’t know how to prove it.

The third picture gives three new parameters, but they cannot all be independent. Indeed at most one is, so the answer should be three, but again I could not find a way to prove it.

Comment: By generic, do you mean parabolic?

Comment: I mean it is parabolic and the plane of the trajectory does not contain the observer. More generally, it is not a “special case”.

Answer (score 0):

I refuse to assume the earth is flat...

But I would guess four, because we are talking about a parabolic curve, which is represented by y = ax²+bx+c. We need to determine the three coefficients a, b and c, but we only obtain the information of the difference between two photos. So to get three differences we need four points.

Comment: Actually we get two parameters from the first picture (the position of the ball) and three from each subsequent picture (position and time). The problem is that not all of these parameters are necessaarily independent for the third and subsequent pictures.

Comment: This answer seems to not include the effects of the camera projection from 3D to the sensor chip plane. Being able to construct the parabola in the camera chip plane gives a surface in 3d "reality", so at best a curve for the collision with the ground. But where on this curve will the ball actually fall down?

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer would be that the problem is unsolvable. No matter how many pictures you take, range cannot be predicted. Let me illustrate with a more intuitive situation. Suppose you live in a high-rise building, and you have one wall made of glass. You cannot look down on the ground, and don't know how high up you are. You can only look straight ahead. Now, someone from the ground throws a ball up in front of you. You can see the ball go up from a certain point on the floor of your room, reach a maximum height, and go down again from some other point. Suppose you start taking pictures using the same set-up you had before. Would you ever be able to know where the ball will hit the ground? Of course, you can assign origin to be that point where the ball first comes into your sight, have an $x$-axis along the floor of the room and a vertical $y$-axis, and let the time be $t=0$ at that instant. If you then take one other picture, that would be enough for you to draw the trajectory of the ball with respect to the coordinate system I described. However, since you do not know what the equation of the horizontal "ground line" is, that is, don't know how far below you the ground lies, you can never figure out where exactly the point of projection of the ball was, or where it will end up.
Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: I see your argument, but I think it applies only if one doesn’t know the elevation. I could have been more clear in the statement: the assumption is that the ground is flat and that the camera is at ground level (or possibly at a known height above ground)

Comment: No no, it's the same thing. Even though in your case you can see the ground, you can't actually "see" it. I mean, when you take a picture at a random point in the trajectory, you have no idea at what time you took the picture, or at what height. So, if the ground level had been a few meters higher or lower, even then the very same trajectory with same velocities at every point could be replicated. One would only have to change initial velocity and angle of projection to do that, which were unknowns anyway.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please put forward your argument if you think otherwise.

Comment: I'm just reading this now, but as far as I can see your "intuitive" explanation is a different problem. Everything you've said to prove that "it's the same thing" is directly contradicted by the original problem statement. (True, it is only just before I wrote this that we were told explicitly that you know the exact height of the camera above the ground, but "standing in a field" implied the same thing before.)

Comment: I did not know that the OP had edited his answer. If we are standing in a field without knowing the time or velocity or position of projection, and can't measure exact heights, it's in fact exactly the same problem. Just being able to see the ground makes no difference if you can't quantify the fact.

Comment: Perhaps this would make it clearer. If we click two photos, that is enough for us to determine the trajectory of the ball, keeping point of first photo as origin, and axes horizontal and vertical. Now, in this coordinate system, we can draw the trajectory of the ball, but we still have no idea what equation the line has. Let the trajectory of the ball be, say, $y=x(1-x)$. But we don't know if the ground level is $y=0$, or $y=-11$, or something else altogether. Hence we never know the range.